# Change default app icon and loading screen in SpriteBuilder

Tags: ios, image, cocos2d-iphone, icons, spritebuilder

I'm making a game with SpriteBuilder and cocos2d in Objective-C and don't know how to change the default loading image an app icons in SpriteBuilder. 
Does anyone know how to do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't something you can change from within the Spritebuilder app. You simply do it by replacing the images that you'll find in the `Source->Resources`subfolder in your project folder. There you'll find all the different `default.png` images (for the different resolutions), and the icons (in the `icons`folder). All you have to do, really, is to replace them with your own designs.

Comment: can't I use SpriteBuilder to automatically resize the app icon with the highest resolution or have I to make this myself?

Comment: Not really. I guess you could use SB for automatic scaling, but it won't work with just one image as there are a number of different resolutions that you need. SB will only do 4x, 2x and 1x. But there are tools and scripts out there that you can use.

Answer (score 0):

my solution was to create a Launch Screen.xib file (File, New, File, iOS, User Interface, LaunchScreen). Then in the general settings for the project, where it says Launch Image Source, click "Don't use assets catalog." The last step is to set the launch screen file to your new .xib file, if you didn't change the name like I didn't, just type in Launch Screen.xib

Now if you launch your app, you should see that the loading screen is the same as the screen made in the launch screen.xib file.

The downside to this is that (I think) you can't use your own image. However most launch images tend to be a simple background color and some text, which is easily editable in Xcode.

The upside to this is that Xcode handles all scaling and aspect ratios, so you only need to set everything to percents and make one image, as appose to creating many different sized images.

Hope this helps.